# What makes the spelling of "psychedelic" a mongrel spelling?

Tags: etymology

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelia#cite_note-7), Richard Evans Schultes thought that *psychedelic* was a mongrel spelling of the word. The other option was *phanerothyme*. Apparently, they are both constructed from Greek words for "spirit" and "manifest". In the case of *psychedelic*, *psyche-* is Greek for spirit, *-del-* is derived from *dēlos*, which is Greek for *manifest*. In the case of *phanerothyme*, *phanero-* is Greek for *manifest*, and *-thyme* is Greek for *spirit*.

How come there are two spellings derived from Greek, and why was one of them considered a mongrel spelling by Schultes?

Comment: You just wanted to use the word mongrel. Am I right? :) Maybe he didn't know. Those words are unrelated, root-wise. [I wish my name had that accent mark. Swedish, right? So cute.]

Comment: @Lambie: "Swedish right?" As a pre-Covid-social-distancing, mountain-hiking, brunost-eating Norwegian that would leave any Swede in a cloud of snow down a ski track, I am mightily offended. *gulps down a horn of mead*

Comment: Oh my gosh: so very sorry. :) Really. It's that I could not tell just from the letter....[Is mead good? And do you really drink it? I'd like to try it. :)]

Comment: It's okay, so long as you agree that the Norwegians were the coolest Vikings.

Comment: Of course, I agree. The coolest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence in the Wiki article is:

> This mongrel **spelling** of the word 'psychedelic' was loathed by
> American ethnobotanist Richard Evans Schultes, but championed by
> Timothy Leary, who thought it sounded better.

The reference Wiki cites for this statement explains that
Schultes was objecting to the spelling, not the Greek derivation:

> Schultes cautioned Leary that the word, meaning "mind manifester," was
> **appropriate**, but the **spelling** was incorrect. The proper Greek was
> "psych**o**delic," and Schultes was concerned lest a Harvard man be
> associated with the bastardization of a classical language. Leary
> suggested that "psych**e**delic" sounded better. [Wade Davis; *One
> River:One River: Explorations and Discoveries in the Amazon Rain Forest*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/One_River/LmNgsXKmE_IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22lest%20a%20Harvard%20man%20be%22) p.120 (1996)

The OED gives the etymology as:

> **Irregularly** < ancient Greek ψυχή psyche n. + δηλοῦν to make manifest,
> reveal ( < δῆλος manifest, visible: see delomorphic adj.) + -ic
> suffix.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/psychedelic) and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/psychedelic) also label the formation as irregular.

Note that the other (non-adopted) proposal

> "phanerothyme," from the Greek terms for "manifest" (φανερός) and
> "spirit" (θύμος)

begins instead with a *combining form*, "phanero-", as "psych**o**delic" would.

If the Wiki contributor had written, say, *unorthodox spelling* instead of *mongrel spelling*, perhaps readers wouldn't be confused.

Comment: It should perhaps be made explicit that whatever reasons there might be for and against using *phanerothyme*, they are largely independent of the arguably unusual morphology of *psych**e**delic*, which could be made to fit the more usual pattern by a simple substitution of *o* for *e*. While both *θύμος* and *ψυχή* can be translated as *spirit*, they are not interchangeable, so the choice between *psychedelic/psychodelic* and *phanerothyme* should depend on what the intended meaning is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the **e** that's a problem. **-delic** isn't right either. It should be **psychodelotic**.

See Nick Nicholas's [erudite and amusing rant on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-English-words-composed-of-Greek-derived-morphemes-and-or-affixes-that-aren-t-actually-Greek-words-and-only-exist-in-English).

Summary:

1. Greek uses **o** as a linking vowel.
2. **delic** is derived from the verb stem **del-**; the appropriate combining form would be **-delot**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "erudite and amusing" is an understatement about a *fantastic* rant. I always enjoy when a classicist enhances an argument with "herp derp" or "HULK SMASH". Thumbs up.

Comment: @Yorik I second that, it was an hilarious read.